# How to capture the date timestamp in Snowflake database in a C# console application?

Tags: c#, .net, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I want to capture these two columns (datatype- timestamp) into a variable in C#.
[image]

I have captured the other variables of string datatype like this to which it gives correct output

```
                string query_id = reader.GetString(11);
                string task_name = reader.GetString(0);
                string database_name = reader.GetString(5);
                string schema_name = reader.GetString(3);
```

How do I capture the timestamps into a variable as reading by string doesn't give the correct column?

Comment: Is there a `GetDateTime`? Or `GetDateTimeOffset`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetimeoffset?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0